# Add time entries to Pandas data series based on interpolation of existing values

Tags: python, pandas, time, interpolation, series

I have an annual pandas data series that looks like:

```
Year          Price
1940-12-31    33.85
1941-12-31    33.85
1942-12-31    33.85
1943-12-31    33.85
1944-12-31    33.85
1945-12-31    34.71
1946-12-31    34.71
1947-12-31    34.71
1948-12-31    34.71
1949-12-31    31.69
1950-12-31    34.72
```

I am new to pandas data series, but I believe the dates are an index because when I print the table it states there is only 1 column.

I want to change it to monthly and then fill in interpolated data for the missing months based on a linear progression from one point to the next. So for example, here's a sample for 1949 that includes the missing months and the interpolation:

```
Date        Price
1948-12-31  34.71
1949-01-31  34.46
1949-02-28  34.21
1949-03-31  33.96
1949-04-30  33.70
1949-05-31  33.45
1949-06-30  33.20
1949-07-31  32.95
1949-08-31  32.70
1949-09-30  32.45
1949-10-31  32.19
1949-11-30  31.94
1949-12-31  31.69
```

The formula for these 1949 interpolated values is ([Price at end of 1949]-[Price at end of 1948]) / 12 + Previous month's Price

I am fairly new to Pandas and python, so please pardon me if the question has been asked elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code will do the job:

```
df['Price'].resample('M').interpolate()
```

replace df with the name of your DataFrame.
resample('M') change the frequency of the series to monthly. (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html)

interpolate() uses linear interpolation by default which is what you wanted, but it has many other options available. (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.interpolate.html)

This will work assuming that you have a DataFrame which is correctly indexed with DatetimeIndex (this should be the case if I understood your description well). You can check if it is in fact the case by

```
df.index
```

If the index is set correctly you will see something like this as output:

```
DatetimeIndex(['1940-12-31', '1941-12-31', '1942-12-31', '1943-12-31',
           '1944-12-31', '1945-12-31', '1946-12-31', '1947-12-31',
           '1948-12-31', '1949-12-31', '1950-12-31'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='A-DEC', tz=None)
```